# Python, how to assign boolean comparison operators to variables?

Tags: python, boolean-operations

I'd like to asign these operators to variables.
I have a flag that if is set to `True` uses `>` or `>=` in certain conditions, but when I set the flag to `False` I want to use `<` or `<=` instead.

Example:

```
up_down: bool = True
if up_down:
   flag1 = data['foo'] > data['foo'].shift(x)
   flag2 = data['foo'] >= data['foo2']
else:
   flag1 = data['foo'] < data['foo'].shift(x)
   flag2 = data['foo'] <= data['foo2']
```

I want to achieve the same without duplicating the code, so the code would look like&work this:

```
if up_down:
  var1 = ">"
  var2 = ">="
else:
  var1 = "<"
  var2 = "<="
flag1 = data['foo'] var1 data['foo'].shift(x)
flag2 = data['foo'] var2 data['foo2']
```

Is it possible?

Comment: All the operators as functions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: from a stylistic point of view, this is a very bad idea. The code is less readable and this is a very unusual approach. What's wrong with the initial solution?

Comment: @anon01 Nothing is wrong honestly, but I thought It would be better if I wasn't duplicating the code and will cut unnecessery code.
So you're suggesting to leave it as is?

Comment: Style is always subject to interpretation, but casting operators as variables is quite unusual - yes, I would definitely suggest the former, at least in a professional setting

Comment: @anon01 Thank you, you've cleared some things for me :)